# Div with text : thick border is pushing text down - how to avoid it?

Tags: html, css

In the middle cell I'd like to use a thicker `border` to let the color be more easily seen but I noticed that the thicker border is pushing text down (here I made it muck more thicker to display it clearly). Is this behavior to be expected?

```css
.a {
  border: 6px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control a">abc 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control b">abc 2</div>
    </td>
    </table
```

[image]

Following an example of this behavior

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpsg52k/24/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested the style that is causing this behavior is the following

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; // 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `line-height` property in your CSS to align contents vertically especially when container is inside the container, for example when content is closer with **south** `border` you can set the `line-height` to `-20px` if the whole `height` of the container is
exactly `20px` but is not a must is just what center content and reverse when content is closer with the **north** `border` let make it clear by come up with an example

---

```css
.a {
  border: 6px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control a">abc 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control b">abc 2</div>
    </td>
</table>
```

now you can see the text is in center in bellow example and guess this will answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *no*, not necessarily. Here a example:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 6px;
  min-width: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.b {
  border-color: #00b2ff;
  border-width: 5px;
  min-width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control a">aaa</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control b">fdfdd</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="form-control c">8563</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I guess that in your example there are some styles affecting the blue cell to behave different from the outer ones!

**Use your inspector and have a look in the "computed" tab to compare the styles, that are applied.**